# Fast selection of a percentage of elements between ranges

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

Given pre-defined ranges, a list of percentages, and some data, I need to randomly select a *percentage* of IDs from those elements that are located between each range.

The code below shows how I do it, and the `for` block is currently the bottleneck. I'm sure this could be made faster probably with some vectorization, but I don't know how.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

# Generate some random data
N = 1000
aa = np.random.uniform(12., 20., N)
# Define edges/ranges.
edges = np.array([16.67666667, 16.77721569, 16.87776471, 16.97831373,
                  17.07886275, 17.17941176, 17.27996078, 17.3805098,
                  17.48105882, 17.58160784, 17.68215686, 17.78270588,
                  17.8832549, 17.98380392, 18.08435294, 18.18490196,
                  18.28545098, 18.386])
# Percentage of elements in 'aa' that will be kept for each 'edges' range.
perc = np.random.uniform(0., 1., len(edges) - 1)

# Locate indexes of 'aa' elements within each 'edges' range.
c_indx = np.searchsorted(edges, aa, side='left')

# THIS IS THE BOTTLENECK
cc = []
# For each defined percentage value (one per edge range).
for i, p in enumerate(perc):
    # Locate IDs of lements within each range. Use 'i + 1' since the first
    # edge range (ie: those elements with c_indx=0) are discarded.
    idxs = np.where(c_indx == i + 1)[0]
    # Shuffle IDs within this edge range (in place)
    np.random.shuffle(idxs)
    # Estimate the number of elements from 'aa' to keep for
    # this range, given the fixed percentage 'p'.
    d = int(round(idxs.size * p, 0))
    # Store the correct percentage of random IDs from 'aa' for this range.
    cc.append(idxs[:d])

# Final list (flattened)
cc = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(cc))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could reduce the workload inside the loop by computing `idxs` by simple slicing of the sorted indices of `c_indx` that we could compute before going into the loop.

Hence, one solution would be -

```
sidx = c_indx.argsort()
sc = c_indx[sidx]
idx = np.flatnonzero(sc[1:] != sc[:-1])+1
for i, p in enumerate(perc):
    idxs = sidx[idx[i]:idx[i+1]]
    # ..rest of the code stays the same
```

Comment: This is about ~10% faster than my code. I was sure that it could be reduced by a lot more. If no better answer comes along, I'll mark this one as accepted. Thanks Divakar.

Comment: @Gabriel There could be one based on the broadcasting one we tackled the other day, but don't feel going that deeper at the moment :)

Answer (score 0):

You already have the info you are getting from the np.where from your searchsorted call. Why not use a dict?

```
mydict = {}

for i,j in enumerate(c_indx):
    mydict.setdefault(j,[]).append(i)
```

This part of the code then takes 57.2us for me, instead of 300. We can keep the data in a list for some more speed too.

```
cc = []

for i, p in enumerate(perc):
    # Locate IDs of lements within each range. Use 'i + 1' since the first
    # edge range (ie: those elements with c_indx=0) are discarded.
    idxs = mydict[i + 1]
    # Shuffle IDs within this edge range (in place)
    np.random.shuffle(idxs)
    # Estimate the number of elements from 'aa' to keep for this range, given the fixed percentage 'p'.
    d = int(round(len(idxs) * p, 0))
    # Store the correct percentage of random IDs from 'aa' for this range.
    cc.append(idxs[:d])
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the improvement you report. Your code actually takes twice as much time as mine in my tests.

Comment: I reported the wrong time, but it is faster for me either way. There is a another speed up in there with the new edit too.

Comment: That's strange. With your new code, 10000 runs of my code (defined as a function between the `c_indx = np.searchsorted()` and the `cc.append()` lines) take ~3.3s. Your code (adding the necessary `c_indx = np.searchsorted()` line) takes ~5.2s...

Comment: I'm running Python 2.7. Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: I guess the dict construction is slow - I'm using %%timeit in a notebook with the lines pasted in the second part of the answer. Python 3.6.

Comment: That's it then. Could you test it adding the dict generation?